# Is the argsort function differentiable in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

By this I mean, can I include it in a loss function and have autodiff function properly?

The `raw_ops` docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops) has no listing for `sort` or `argsort`.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k ?

Comment: This: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argsort

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run the following experiment in colab

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[4.0, 2.1, 1.0]])
w = tf.Variable([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], name='w')

y_true = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]])

@tf.function
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    indices = tf.argsort(y_pred)
    x = tf.gather(y_pred, indices, axis=-1)
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true - x))

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  y = x * w
  loss = loss_fn(y_true, y)

tape.gradient(loss, [w])
```

The computed loss in 1.01 and the gradients for w seem to make sense to me.
So I would say the answer is yes, if you are using argsort() for indexing purposes. If you have something else in mind maybe you can tweak the example above and figure out if the gradients behave as you expect.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP was wondering the same thing that I am - whether or not there is a "gradient" for "sorting", which seems like a non-differentiable operation, but when I run your code, the answer seems to be "No, there isn't." The gradient returned is the same as what the gradient would be if, instead of sorting ```y_pred```, ```y_true``` had been in the "same" order.  That's good for me; that's what I was hoping for.  I was worried that TF might add some component to the gradient associated with the sorting operation, instead of just sorting.